# Google Chrome not loading js files one of three instances

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Strange issue (and not too sure how to diagnose it).

I have a problem with Chrome not loading js files (or at least not appearing to load according to the console.log if put everywhere).

Site runs fine using Chrome on development machine and on test site. Alas, no go on deployment site.

Deployment site is "naked domain": https://example.com; test site is a subdomain: http://test.example.com and of course local is http://localhost:blah. Development subdomain has the same settings as deployment domain.

All script sourcing is in the head, tried disabling https and the only other differentiating factor is not having a host or alias fqdn. (This is where I think the issue is but I cannot confirm it--seems my google-foo is weak.)

NOTE: Safari, Opera, Mozilla, IE all work without any issue.

(I've spent two days on this and I may just be tired of bashing my head against the same repeated posts--so if this is a duplicate please point me there and I'll be on my way, thanks)

Answer (score 0):

OK, now I wish I could delete this question: you know how you find the answer sometimes when you give up looking?

In the developer window, I selected disable cache...there was the answer. One my second test client I selected the Clear browsing data--and it worked.